# Unwanted Lines Included On Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an extension for Google Chrome and I'm noticing an issue where there's a small white line at the bottom and right side of my popup. Not sure what could be adding this here since I'm not changing the margin anywhere in my CSS.

[image: Screenshot]

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/popup.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mainContainer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.css:

```
:root {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    background-color: #262b40;
}

.mainContainer {
    width: 40rem;
    height: 40rem;
}
```

Comment: added screenshot to question

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: tooled around with the dimensions of the div in chrome devtools and this behavior occurs with anything 400px or wider, chalking it up to a bug and going to set the width just below 400px.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your monitor's resolution scale is 125% I have the same issue however 100% shows no weird lines. It's a bug, nothing to do with HTML really. I might try and report it to Chrome, it's kind of annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal & vertical Line could be the scroll bars.
can you specify the max height & max width of the container so that it will automatically be hidden.

you can also use css property to hide the scroll bars.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: there's isn't any scrolling in the container, but I tried adding this CSS property anyway and no difference

Comment: can you post the html that your trying to display it on the click of chrome extension?

Comment: the html is posted in the question. The actual html for the extension is more involved so I wrote this barebones code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: did you try adding margin:0 to the body? also try with padding:0 .

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the same issue that was happening to my extension popup, but since it seems related and I ended up here looking for an answer to a similar problem, I'll post my case and solution.

The code in my popup.html is basically a root div with all the content inside. This root div has a dark background color applied. It's surrounded by undesired white space.

Here's what Chrome was rendering before I applied some extra CSS:

[image]

Here's the CSS I've applied to correct this:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 0;
}
```

Here's how it looks now:

[image]